# Two over-complicated UART interrupt handlers for SIM900 GSM module

Tags: c, embedded

`UARTIntHandler0` interfaces to the USB UART for debugging.

`UARTIntHandler1` interfaces to the SIM900 GSM module.

The purpose of `UARTIntHandler0` is very simple - grab an incoming character and push it to UART1 (the GSM module).

`UARTIntHandler1` is more complicated. In "talk mode," it should allow the user to talk directly to the GSM module - that is, any characters coming on the UART are simply pushed to the other UART so the user can see them via terminal connection.

In normal mode, the interrupt is triggered by any input from the GSM, and does some processing if this input is a message notification. Any other input is ignored by the interrupt handler (but still populates the buffer, where other portions of the code can access it).

I know that the `UARTIntHandler1` (and possibly the other as well) is too big for an interrupt routine: When the program is done, there will be at least seven interrupt sources (GSM UART, console UART, ADC, three timers, and hardware interrupt from keypad) so I want to keep them short.

**My question is**, how much should I expect it to do in this situation, and how much should I hand off to a different function by setting flags for the main program? Please note this code is working *most of the time,* but it's when it doesn't work (poor cell signal, long messages, etc) that it really hurts. I am suspicious that my interrupt handling is the problem.

In my main program, I have a superloop running which periodically checks if the message count has been incremented.

Some global stuff:

```
// Used by UART interrupt handlers
unsigned char var;                  // Incoming UART character
unsigned char ptr[10000];           // Array for storing incoming UART characters
unsigned long i;                    // UART character pointer.
unsigned long ulStatus0,ulStatus1;  // To hold the interrupt status
```

The console UART:

```
void
UARTIntHandler0(void)
{
    // Get the interrupt status.
    ulStatus0 = ROM_UARTIntStatus(UART0_BASE, true);

    // Clear the asserted interrupts
    ROM_UARTIntClear(UART0_BASE, ulStatus0);

    // Loop while there are characters in the receive FIFO.
    while(ROM_UARTCharsAvail(UART0_BASE))
    {
        // Grab a character
        var = (unsigned char)ROM_UARTCharGetNonBlocking(UART0_BASE);

        // Hold it
        ptr[i] = var;

        // Mirror it to GSM
        ROM_UARTCharPutNonBlocking(UART1_BASE, ptr[i]);

        // Proceed to next character
        i++;
    }
}
```

The GSM UART:

```
void
UARTIntHandler1(void)
{
    char *msgCountStr;                  // Number of new messages
    static char g_cInput[128];          // String input to a UART

    // Get the interrupt status.
    ulStatus1 = ROM_UARTIntStatus(UART1_BASE, true);

    // Clear the asserted interrupts.
    ROM_UARTIntClear(UART1_BASE, ulStatus1);

    // Interrupt trigger means GSM is on
    if ( GSMoff ) { GSMoff = false; }

    // Loop while there are characters in the receive FIFO.
    while(ROM_UARTCharsAvail(UART1_BASE))
    {
        // Grab a character
        var = (unsigned char)ROM_UARTCharGetNonBlocking(UART1_BASE);

        // Hold it
        ptr[i] = var;

        // In talk mode mirror to console...
        if (talkMode) { ROM_UARTCharPutNonBlocking(UART0_BASE, ptr[i]); }

        // ...or else see if it's a message notification (like +CMTI: "SM",12):
        else 
        {
            if(ptr[i-3] == 'C' && ptr[i-2] == 'M' && ptr[i-1] == 'T'&& ptr[i] == 'I')
            {
                // Grab everything
                UART1gets(g_cInput,sizeof(g_cInput));

                // Stop after newline character
                msgCountStr = strtok(g_cInput,"\n");

                // Parse out the message count (terminate with null to store)
                strncpy(msgCountStr,msgCountStr+7,3);
                msgCountStr[3]='\0';

                // Convert to integer
                sscanf(msgCountStr, "%d", &msgCount);

                // Tell the user
                UART0printf("\n\r>>> %u NEW MESSAGE(S)",msgCount);
            }
        }
        // Proceed to next character
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The best way to do this depends on how large a hardware UART rx buffer you've got, and whether the MCU supports DMA or not. But if you are looking for the best solution for a given hardware, I think the question will get much better answers if asked at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: What is `i`? What is `ptr`? As presented, the code has many obvious bugs and cannot be reviewed. Voting to close, sorry.

Comment: We need your full code to be able to review it. As it stands, this post is **off-topic**.

Comment: I am not sure the right way to proceed in code review... this is working code, with bugs - if I didn't have bugs, why would I post? And what does "full" code mean? Everything involved in making this run is around 10,000 lines. I agree that leaving out the global declarations was a mistake, so I've added them. Still learning how to proceed here...

Comment: Full code means the code which is necessary to run this code snippet (not the 10000 lines, just the ones necessary to be able to figure out what it does and how to improve and, if found, the current bugs in your code), also reviewing is for improving your currently working code, not fixing the bugs you know that exist in said code.

Comment: Can the people who closed this tell me specifically what I would need to include to not be off-topic? These are interrupt handlers for an embedded application on custom hardware, so including full working code is patently impossible. Is code review not the right place for this?

Answer (score 2):

1. `UARTIntHandler1(void)` does far too much for an interrupt service routine (ISR).  The single biggest issue is interrupt latency: time from when an interrupt occurs to it being handled.  This function call routines  *in a loop*:  `strtok()`,  `strncpy()` and potential CPU count sink-hole `UART0printf("\n\r>>> %u NEW MESSAGE(S)",msgCount);`.  These are message length dependent functions that  could take a long time in a worst case scenario. It delays the time that *another* interrupt waits before being handled.


   <kbd>ISR</kbd>: get in, do minimal work of O(1) and get out.

   Better to have the main program handle all this string processing.
2. Potential infinite loop.  An ISR should never loop forever like with `while( ROM_UARTCharsAvail(UART0_BASE) )`.  This depends on functionally correct coding and hardware. Hardware sometimes 1) fails or 2) works in ways code just did not expect.  Better to limit the number of iterations to some fixed value.  If `N` is the theoretical max number, use a for loop `(for i=0; i<(N+2)  && ROM_UARTCharsAvail(UART0_BASE); i++)` and set a reportable error if code loops too often.
3. Below is scary.  1) `msgCountStr` could return `NULL` and `strncpy(NULL, ...` is UB. 2)  `strncpy(msgCountStr,msgCountStr+7,3);` by itself is UB, use `memmove()`.  3) `strtok()` affects global memory and *never* should be used in an ISR.

   ```
   msgCountStr = strtok(g_cInput,"\n");
   strncpy(msgCountStr,msgCountStr+7,3);
   ```
4. Not checking the result of `sscanf(msgCountStr, "%d", &msgCount)` can lead to all sorts of trouble as if the conversion fails, `msgCount` *may* be left in its former state.  Code safe: check return values.
5. Re-design idea:  Create a software FIFO.  Have the ISR pull data out of the HW FIFO and fill the SW FIFO.  Then in the main loop, code can process the SW FIFO at its leisure.

Comment: I was suspicious of some of the things you mentioned. I'm going to work on re-designing this code and report back. Thanks!